# How to create an rss.xml feed on my Drupal 7 site?

Tags: feeds

I would like to set up an RSS feed on a new site, but having never done this before I am unsure of where to start.

I've got an rss icon on my page and I would like to create a http://demo.drupalizing.com/corporateclean/rss.xml equivalent which is available on this demo site:

http://demo.drupalizing.com/?theme=corporateclean

How do I do this?

Comment: are you using views module?

Comment: I have used views module before @Aboodred1

Comment: Is it possible for me to create a rss.xml file using the views module? I have never done this before @Aboodred1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said you're using the [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module, so yes -- very doable:

1. Go to `admin/structure/views/add`.
2. Give the view a name (required), add any (basic) additional configuration options you might want, and then under *Create a page*, select *Include an RSS feed*.
3. Give the RSS feed a path (you'll see the box).
4. *Continue & edit*, configure the view like normal, then save.

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell how images can be handled here?, because i'm not able to get image field data.

Comment: and how can you add  these not present fields?
<itunes:owner>
    <itunes:name>name ownerl</itunes:name>
    <itunes:email>email@email.com</itunes:email>
</itunes:owner>

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you still get the error when doing step #4. If that's the case for you,  don't do step #3 and then do step #4. Once you are inside the view, create a view display and modify your field setting when you add them.